# Hashset vs. IQueryable

Tags: c#, linq, generics, data-structures, iqueryable

Recently I was working on implementing a small snippet that caches my results and the way I was doing it was using a Dictionary as follows:

```
 private Dictionary<ID, IQueryable<Results>> _simpleCache;
```

The idea was to search for all the results that have the id specified by 'ID' and if the Dictionary contains the key == id, we simply search through the values present in the IQueryable instead of making a database trip.

I was going over this piece of logic this morning and I was thinking about replacing the IQueryable with HashSet as follows:

```
private Dictionary<ID, HashSet<Results>> _simpleCache;
```

Is making this change advisable?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, it is.  Generally, [`IQueryable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.iqueryable.aspx) implies that you are using a data source provider which is queried each time the queryable is enumerated (of course, this isn't *always* the case, as you can call [AsQueryable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353734.aspx) extension method on an [`IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx) which will give you an `IQueryable<T>` implementation over the `IEnumerable<T>` implementation).

To that end, storing the `IQueryable<Results>` in a dictionary doesn't actually prevent any hits to the data source when you enumerate through it a second time.  It will make a request to the data provider *every* time you enumerate through it.

Because of this, you typically want to materialize the results on the client side, usually calling the [`ToList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx) or [`ToArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298736.aspx) extension methods, and then using `IEnumerable<Results>` or `Results[]` as the `TValue` type parameter of your dictionary.

Note that you *could* use a [`HashSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) to store your objects, but you have to make sure that you implement [`IEquatable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx) and override [`GetHashCode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx) so that the default equality comparer will perform a comparison on the `ID` instance exposed by the `Results` type, either that, or you have to provide an [`IEqualityComparer<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx) implementation that will do the same thing.  It's more than likely that you are using designer-generated code, and it will not do this for you, and your objects will have equality determined by reference, not by value.